# difference between netty running on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, netty, epoll, iocp

Netty's I/o multiplexing depends on epoll on a Linux system, but is the performance the same when running netty on a Windows operating system?

Windows without epoll,how does netty work?iocp?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it this way:
By default, Netty uses Java NIO which is independent of the OS you're running on.
However, additional performance and some functionality can be gained by leveraging native support ( e.g. epoll for Linux or kqueue for macos ). 
So far, there's no native enhancements in Netty for Windows, but the base java NIO still serves well, and NIO does not depend on epoll.

Comment: does this mean that when I run a Netty NIO application on Linux, it would behave as if it is Epoll? Would the performance be the same as if I wrote it from scratch using EpollDatagramChannel, or would it still behave as if it is NioDatagramChannel, but slightly better performance compared to running on windows?

Comment: So far as I know, Netty does not, as yet, have the ability to automatically switch to the native implementation (i.e. epoll for Linux, or kqueue for MacOS). And even if it did (which I think it does/will not), you would still need to have the native libraries accessible in the classpath. But Netty does provide some useful static functions like (and I am coda-phrasing) isEpollAvailable() so you can orchestrate the construction of the most optimal factory according to platform. It's a bit of extra hassle though, and you may want to consider if you need the extra "oomph" of the native impl.